# How to fix JQuery Datepicker dateformat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I already asked one question about datepicker yesterday, but now I have faced a new problem that I was not able to fix by myself. I'm using JQuery Datepicker to make a calendar where I can choose a date range. When I'm trying to change dateformat from default (which is `mm/dd/yy`) to `dd.mm.yy` it fails with error and stop working when I'm trying to select any date. Also with default dateformat doesn't work my code to have a default selected dates on load.

This is my code with current datepicker settings (it makes possible to choose date range and style it with additional classes, also it places dates *from* and *to* into hidden inputs and visible div's), with full styling it looks like on screenshot:

datepicker range work:

[image: datepicker range work]

Hope you will be able to help me with this case!

```js
// This code doesn't work with default dateformat
// start date on default
//$('#start-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
//$('.start-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
// end date on default
//$('#end-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
//\$('.end-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        
        // jquery datepicker settings
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                minDate: 0,
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $('#start-date').val());
                  
                    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $('#end-date').val());
                   
                    if (date1 && date && (date1.getTime() == date.getTime())) {
                        return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
                    }
                    if (date2 && date && (date2.getTime() == date.getTime())) {
                        return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
                    }

                    if (date >= date1 && date <= date2) {
                        return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
                    }

                    return [true, '', ''];
                },
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $('#start-date').val());
                    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $('#end-date').val());
                    if (!date1 || date2) {
                        $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                        $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                        $('#end-date').val('');
                        $('.end-date-visible').text('');
                        $(this).datepicker('option', dateText);
                    } else {
                        if (new Date(dateText) < date1) {
                            var sDate = $('#start-date').val();
                            $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                            $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                            $(this).datepicker('option', null);

                            $('.end-date-visible').text(sDate);
                            $('#end-date').val(sDate);

                        } else {
                            $('.end-date-visible').text(dateText);
                            $('#end-date').val(dateText);
                            $(this).datepicker('option', null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
td.ui-state-selected-range:first-child a {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
td.ui-state-selected-range:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.ui-red-start a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-start a:before {
    content: '';
    right: -1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ui-red-end a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-end a:before {
    content: '';
    left: -1px;
    right: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-left: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ui-state-selected-range .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background: #f8c3b1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="text" id="start-date" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type="text" id="end-date" style="visibility:hidden">

<div class="start-date-visible"></div>
<div class="end-date-visible"></div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// This code doesn't work with default dateformat
// start date on default
//$('#start-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
//$('.start-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
// end date on default
//$('#end-date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
//\$('.end-date-visible').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));

// jquery datepicker settings
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#start-date').val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#end-date').val());

            // var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#end-date').val());

            if (date1 && date && (date1.getTime() == date.getTime())) {
                return [true, 'ui-red-start', ''];
            }
            if (date2 && date && (date2.getTime() == date.getTime())) {
                return [true, 'ui-red-end', ''];
            }
            
            //change here for selection
            
            if(date1 && date2 && date1-date2){
             if (date2<=date && date<=date1) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
             }
            }
            else if(date1 && date2 && date2-date1){
             if (date2<=date && date<=date1) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
             }
            }

            if (date1<=date && date<=date2) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-selected-range', ''];
            }

            return [true, '', ''];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#start-date').val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#end-date').val());
            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                $('#end-date').val('');
                $('.end-date-visible').text('');
                $(this).datepicker('option', dateText);
            } else {
                if (new Date(dateText) < date1) {
                    var sDate = $('#start-date').val();
                    $('.start-date-visible').text(dateText);
                    $('#start-date').val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker('option', null);

                    $('.end-date-visible').text(sDate);
                    $('#end-date').val(sDate);

                } else {
                    $('.end-date-visible').text(dateText);
                    $('#end-date').val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker('option', null);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
td.ui-state-selected-range:first-child a {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
td.ui-state-selected-range:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.ui-red-start a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-start a:before {
    content: '';
    right: -1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ui-red-end a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F29676;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
}
.ui-red-end a:before {
    content: '';
    left: -1px;
    right: 50%;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f29676;
    border-left: none;
    background-color: #f8c3b1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ui-state-selected-range .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #f29676 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background: #f8c3b1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="text" id="start-date" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type="text" id="end-date" style="visibility:hidden">

<div class="start-date-visible"></div>
<div class="end-date-visible"></div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Use `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',` and while parsing the date use same format to parse it.

Comment: It works, thank you! But now, when I'm trying to choose date range from max to min it doesn't make a visual selection, if you choose date from min to max it works fine, what could happen to it?

Comment: thank you, it solves the problem, except that first and last selected dates when choosing from max to min aren't change their visual direction, anyway I will try to solve this by myself, thanks!
[sccreenshot](https://pp.userapi.com/c841436/v841436928/1479e/UPNiX_4w324.jpg)